# What attribute and value can you use to cause an <a> element to open the link in a new browser tab?

Tags: html

What attribute and value can you use to cause an  element to open the link in a new browser tab?

Comment: What does Google tell you?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

To open a link in a new tab you need to add target="_blank" to the anchor tag.

```
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a/" target="_blank">Mozilla</a>
```

Mozilla

Answer (score 0):

You can use  with the attribute target

```
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">The page will open in another tab.</a>
```